# decltype of ternary operator is different in MSVC ~C++17

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++20

[`std::common_reference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_reference) uses `decltype` to the ternary operator `?:`

> Otherwise, if `decltype(false? val<T1>() : val<T2>())`, where val is a function template `template<class T> T val();`, is a valid type, then the member type type names that type;

But MSVC says `decltype(false? val<int&&>() : val<int&&>())` is `int` in the below code in below C++20.

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
T val();

int main() {
    static_assert(std::is_same<int&&, decltype(val<int&&>())>::value, "1");
    static_assert(std::is_same<int&&, decltype(false?val<int&&>():val<int&&>())>::value, "2");
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/KE9PnGvd5

What is a *correct* behavior?

Is this an MSVC defect?

Comment: The behavior should be to return an rvalue reference here. [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator) substantiates this with "`(4) If E2 and E3 are glvalues of the same type and the same value category, then the result has the same type and value category, and is a bit-field if at least one of E2 and E3 is a bit-field.`". cppreference isn't a normative reference of course, but is still a good sanity-check. It's possible MSVC is preserving this bad behavior to prevent breaking previously compiling code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an MSVC bug.

The rules for the *conditional operator* are in [[expr.cond]](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.cond). There are many parts of those rules that are quite complex, but this case is actually the easy one:

> If the second and third operands are glvalues of the same value category and have the same type, the result is of that type and value category and it is a bit-field if the second or the third operand is a bit-field, or if both are bit-fields.

That's our case: we have two `int&&`s, which are glvalues of the same value category and the same type - so the result is also `int&&`.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-ternary

Comment: @T.C. It seems like applying the flag won't affect the STL and can be safely used. Thanks!

Comment: So it isn't a bug, but a by-default non-compliance, as @T.C. 's link to the flag shows.  In short, if you want a more compliant C++ compiler and not one designed for backward compatibility, use `/permissive-`.